# C++ - invalid initialization of reference of type 'node*&' from expression of type 'node'

Tags: c++

I was doing some list exercises but for some reason the compiler notice some problems about the struct node type, but i can not see what is the problem.

I declared normally node structure, in the `addNode(node *&, int)` function i use a
pointer by reference of `node` type for modify the list in the main and a integer for save in the node

```
#include<iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void addNode (node *& ,int); 

int main()
{
    node list;
    
    addNode(list, 24);
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

But when i try to use the function in the main and compile this appear in the compiler:

```
exercise1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
exercise1.cpp:19:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'node*&' from expression of type 'node'
   19 |  addNode(list, 24);
      |          ^~~~
exercise1.cpp:9:15: note: in passing argument 1 of 'void addNode(node*&, int)'
    9 | void addNode (node *& ,int);
      |               ^~~~~~~
```

A `node*&` its a pointer by reference of type `node` for modify `list` in the main, if i put by reference `&list` still happen the same error, before i use the same syntax in other exercises and working

What's happen?

Comment: What is your question? A `node*&` is not `node`. So you should take the address of your node and not the node itself.

Comment: Since `addNode` modifies the pointer it receives, OP should rather pass a pointer and have it modified by the `addNode` function.

Comment: Since you are trying to learn pointers, the first lesson must be that a pointer to a node and a node are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the stupid question, i am actually learning and i don`t see what's happen at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
     node list;
```

is missing a star to declare a pointer. You probably want:

```
int main()
{
     node* list = NULL;
```